# Excel 2021: How to "fill down" an array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to know if there is a way to use a single excel formula to fill down empty element in an array by last non-blank elements.

For example,
Given an excel array =TRANSPOSE({"A","","","B","","","C","D"})
I would like to apply an excel formula so it returns
=TRANSPOSE( {"A","A","A","B","B","B","C","D"})

I tried to use match method like below
=TRANSPOSE(IF({"A","","","B","","","C","D"}<>"",{"A","","","B","","","C","D"},INDEX({"A","","","B","","","C","D"},MATCH(TRUE,{"A","","","B","","","C","D"}<>"",0))))
and it results =TRANSPOSE( {"A","A","A","B","A","A","C","D"})
because MATCH(TRUE,{"A","","","B","","","C","D"}<>"",0) search from the beginning of the array for each element.

I also know it can be done by using =TRANSPOSE(INDEX({"A","","","B","","","C","D"},{1,1,1,4,4,4,7,8})).

However, I cannot find out how to use excel formula to create an array of {1,1,1,4,4,4,7,8}.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: FYI to build a vertical array constant use `;` for example: `{"A" ; "" ; "" ; "B" ; "" ; "" ; "C" ; "" ; ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2021 you can use LET and SEQUENCE:

```
=LET(Arr,{"A";"";"";"B";"";"";"C";"D"}, Seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Arr)), LOOKUP(Seq,IF(LEN(Arr),Seq),Arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do this.

I like [SCAN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/scan-function-d58dfd11-9969-4439-b2dc-e7062724de29):

```
=SCAN(,TRANSPOSE({"A","","","B","","","C","D"}),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",b,a)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you reply. However, can it be done in excel 2020 like I remarked in the title. I think Lambda is a function in excel 365 not in excel 2020.

Comment: Apologies. I wasn't aware there was a 2020 version of Excel, so I assumed it was a typo. Do you have 2019 or 2021?

Comment: Changed the title of the versions of excel from 2020 to 2021. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: Still helpful for those with those functions available!